# Single.Parse() vs using just Console.ReadLine() to read float values

Tags: vb.net

I can add float values obtained from `Console.ReadLine()` and add them together without having to use `Single.Parse(Console.ReadLine())`. Is it better practice to use `Single.Parse()`?

For example:

```
Sub Main()
        Dim num1, num2, sum As Single

        Console.WriteLine("Enter two floating point numbers:")
        'get user input

        Console.Write("First number: ")
        num1 = Console.ReadLine()
        'num1 = Single.Parse(Console.ReadLine())

        Console.Write("Second number: ")
        num2 = Console.ReadLine()
        'num2 = Single.Parse(Console.ReadLine())

        sum = num1 + num2

        Console.WriteLine("sum of " & num1 & " and " & num2 & " is: " & sum)

    End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd go with Double rather than Single. If you ever *need* to use Single, you'll know it. Also, Decimal is normally better for monetary values.

Comment: Users are notoriously untrustworthy. `.TryParse` is a good way to avoid a program crash when a user enters their email instead of a number.  :-)

Comment: Turn on Option Strict and see how that works for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will only compile with `Option Strict Off`.  If you turn `Option Strict On`, you will be forced to do something to explicitly convert the data type, such as `Single.Parse`.

Asking if it's "better" is a matter of opinion, I guess, but I can tell you that the majority of advanced developers far prefer turning `Option Strict On`.  It is much safer, more explicit, and more compatible with other languages, like C#.

Another advantage is that if you were to copy or move the code from a project with `Option Strict Off` to a project with `Option Strict On`, you'd be forced to fix all the problems.  However, when moving code the other way, there won't be anything to fix.  So, even within the same language, it's more compatible to code that way.

Comment: Thanks Steven - I'm learning VB.net and turn Option Strict On is something I had overlooked which created confusion for me.

Comment: FYI, you can turn it on or off at the project level (thereby effecting all the code in the project) or at the file level (which overrides the project-level setting just for the code in that file).  Also, there is an option in Visual Studio where you can set the default project-level setting for new projects.  So, if you turn it on, then every time you create a new VB project, it will automatically turn `Option Strict On` for the new project by default.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to turn Option Strict On. This will show you that indeed, you need to properly convert a string to a Single. This will also help on adding proper error handling.

Comment: I'd say it's not so much good practice to turn it on, as it is _extremely poor practice_ to leave it off. People will make one "good" tradeoff for another. Getting them to understand this isn't just trading good for neutral, but good for very poor, is a better driver for behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It's always good practice to parse. Input from text will be a string, you don't want to do mathematical operations on a string.

It's also good practice to check you have the correct input, this is where 'TryParse' comes in. Here's an example using your previous code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim num1, num2, sum As Single

    Console.WriteLine("Enter two decimal numbers:")

    Console.Write("First number: ")
    Do While Not Single.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), num1)
        Console.Write("Not valid. Please enter a valid decimal number... " & Environment.NewLine)
        Console.Write("First number: ")
    Loop

    Console.Write("Second number: ")
    Do While Not Single.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), num2)
        Console.Write("Not valid. Please enter a valid decimal number... " & Environment.NewLine)
        Console.Write("Second number: ")
    Loop

    sum = num1 + num2
    Console.WriteLine("sum of " & num1 & " and " & num2 & " is: " & sum)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```